# ArcPy error message returns absurd line error

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I am porting an arcpy 10.x script to Pro v3.  The tool returns an error message with a description of the method that failed.  The error message from Pro is also returning the line number where the error is occurring.    The line error from Pro is not the same line shown in the Python IDE.

Here is a screen shot of the error message dialog from ArcGIS Pro with the error info and the line error. Here Pro is telling me that the error is on line 76 at `ExportToJPEG`

[image]

Here is the portion in the script where the error is occurring which is line 84 in my Python IDE.  I know the proper syntax is exportToJPEG() and I have corrected that problem.  My question is why Pro returning line 76 as the error and not line 84 as coded in the script?  Not returning the Python script line number makes it really difficult to troubleshoot scripting tools.

[image]

Comment: I've just discovered a similar problem with its error line number reporting.  It's complete nonsense.  This is in ArcGIS Pro 3.0.3.  I also found that it was incredibly unreliable at keeping saved changes to a script stored within a script tool.  Shockingly bad reliability. 
 It also removes all blank lines (I like blank lines in my code!).  I'm tempted to revert to 2.8.1 which did not have these problems.  But will probably cross my fingers for 3.2 to be better.

Comment: I've just tried the new `.atbx` toolbox format (only recently upgraded to Pro 2.9) and the error line numbers are off by one for me.  Python toolboxes `.pyt` show correct line number though.